# Wit.ai Wrong work of simple intent "Hello"

Tags: wit.ai

I'm using a simple app with one story

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf1yr.png

Entity: user-defined "intent" with value "greetings", search strategy "trait"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBQpz.png

But my bot says "OK Hello" when user types any chain of symbols like "blablabla":

User says: *Hello*

Bot says: **OK Hello**

User says: *Bye*

Bot says: **OK Hello**

User says: *fjkjdskfsdfslfjl*

Bot says: **OK Hello**

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather create a free text/keywords intent called greetings, and add "hello", "yo", "hey" into that entity. Then you can have a trait intent with the value userGreeting. This way your bot can recognize when the user has sent a greeting.

Use free text and keyword entities for words or sentences, while trait entities are for recognizing where the focus should be. But makes sure to not mix them, your entity should be either a trait entity, or keyword and free text.

I'm not sure if my definitions are correct, but at least my bot works! Try it out at https://m.messenger/IGDBcom